# strange Behaviour in form validate

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I Have an action with form submit and with this render after save

```
return $this->render(
            $template,
            array(
                'p' => $p,
                'c' => $c,
            )
        );
```

If Form is not Valid I have the correct "error" in browser.

If I do

```
$a = array(
'p' => $p,
'c' => $c);

  return $this->render($template,$a);
```

When I submit the form with validation error, I don't see the "error" in broswer ( error like "This value is already used.")

**update**

My Problem

```
 if ($this->get('request')->get('new') == 'true') {
        return $this->render(
            $template,
            array(
                'p' => $p,
                'c' => $c,
            )
        );
    } else {
        return $this->render(
            $template,
            array(
                'ps' => $ps,
                'cs' => $cs,
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: what is `$this->get('request')->get('new')`?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. You should paste more details about your action. E.g. which letter ('p', or 'c') is related to your form, and also ask question after update

Comment: thanks for replies. `$this->get('request')->get('new')` it's a parameter come from Twig. `p` it's a query (findall) and `c` it's an action that create forms.